# useState reverts back to initial state after being set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

This component is an empty item slot that renders a lightbox when clicked -- the lightbox allows editing of an item, and then, when closed, should fill the slot with the newly created item.

When the information in the lightbox is changed, it sets `newOption` to the value of that change. When I log `newOption` in the global context, I get the item object, like I'm supposed to. However, when I log `newOption` within the `stopEditOption` function, it has reverted back to its original state of `null`. I'm not sure why it isn't keeping the value that is set with `setNewOption` -- is it because of the lightbox context?

```
export default function PollOptionSlot(props) {
    const {children, onAddOption} = props;
    const lightbox = useContext(LightboxContext);
    const [newOption, setNewOption] = useState(null);

    console.log(newOption);  // this works and logs the newOption as the newly created item, before closing the lightbox

    function stopEditItem() {
        onAddOption(newOption); // this logs as null
        lightbox.setContent(null);
    }

    function openEditor() {
        lightbox.setContent(<div className={Style.itemEditor}><ItemEditor onChange={setNewOption}
                                                                          onSaveButtonClick={stopEditItem}/></div>);
    }

    return <>
        <div className={Style.main} onClick={openEditor}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </>;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried defining your `stopEditItem` function using a useCallback hook with `newOption` in the dependency array?

Comment: @MauriceA. I have, unfortunately that did not change the result

Comment: Can you ensure that the new value is printed in your log statement before the stopEditItem function is executed (i.e. by adding another log statement in the stopEditItem function

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I got it to work by moving the inside of the `lightbox.setContent(` as well as the state management to an external function!